# Same Command, Different Results setFrame: NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nswindow

I'm experiencing what I think is a very strange issue.

First and foremost, my application moves UI elements around the screen using the following example command:

```
    [view setFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0))];
```

I give my users the possibility to resize the application's NSWindow to one other size with this command:

```
    [self.window setFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)) display:YES animate:YES];
```

When in 'resized mode', I obviously change every single `setFrame` command to the appropriate coordinate system.

However, there is an issue: when (if) the user switches back to the original NSWindow size by clicking on the button again, and the application performs the UI movements again, the views that are moved around are not in the location they are supposed to be in.

To clarify: my UI movement code runs fine, over and over, either in normal or resized mode. However, if I switch from one to the other, some items (not all) are shifted.

What could be causing this strange behavior? I'm using the same exact commands (within each screen resolution), and NSLogs confirm the UI elements are in the location that I specified; however, this location is *clearly* not the one I'm attempting to move to.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days and days of trying to figure this out, I've come to the following conclusion: the resizing code simply wasn't working.

I confirmed this by using NSLog after I resized my window. In the end, I changed my resizing code by adding the following line after the traditional `setFrame:` method:

```
    [self.window setContentSize:NSSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake(desiredWidth, desiredHeight))];
```

Answer (score 1):

You've probably set some sort of autoresizing mask in Interface Builder that's interfering with your manual placements. Go in to your nib and remove all the springs and struts in the Size inspector. Although if possible you should let autosizing handle the placement, or move to Auto Layout which was introduced in 10.7.

Comment: That's possible, I'll have to check on it. However, I _am_ using autoresizing, but I still have to move the objects after having resized the window. So, does this mean I should take autoresizing out completely and just use setFrame instead of autoresizing?

Comment: If you need to place all the objects manually, turning off autoresizing will simplify debugging, if nothing else.